# How to implement load balancing in Greenplum

Tags: greenplum

In greenplum all queries goes through master node is there any way to implement load balancing in greenplum?

Comment: The load is spread across the segment hosts.  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: All request comes to master and master re-route it, my question is if large number of queries fire and if master could not handle it or slow in response so what will happen? To avoid this kind of situation I am looking for solution where we can handle master load.

Comment: The master is only involved in preparing the query plan, the real execution happens on the segments. If you want faster query execution, just add more segments, it scales out. If you want to handle master load, beyond just faster queries, please look into resource queues.

Comment: You can also use a connection pooler like pgBouncer which is included with Greenplum.

Comment: Check Resource groups or Resource queues
https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/580/admin_guide/workload_mgmt_resgroups.html